# Nested If Problem using DAX and 3 contexts

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, measure, nested-if

I am having an issue with the below:
[My example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0GsK.jpg)
[additional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBhVs.jpg)

Gross Sales$=Calculate([fbudget],FILTER('DataTbl'[GLNumber=36000]))
Discount$=Calculate([fbudget],FILTER('DataTbl'[GLNumber=44444]))

%Discounts=iferror([Discount$]/[Gross Sales$],0)

The column % discounts and the row Budget vs Actual is my issues. % Discounts is a measure showing Discounts/Gross Sales as a percentage. It gets split out by my three different cases Budget, Actual, and Budget vs Actual. But when it gets to budget vs actual it is still looking at discounts/gross sales instead of taking the difference between the budget% and the Actual%....

I tried making a complicated nested if such that if "Budget" it does discounts/gross sales, if "Actual" it does "discounts/gross sales" but if it is "Budget vs Actual" it does (discount/gross sales) budget-(discount/gross sales) actual but it just gives me an error :(

Comment: Please include in your question what you actually did: the DAX and some raw data so we understand it and can help you.

Comment: I added an additional image and the measures. The additional image is a little shitty, but if you zoom in I think it gives a better idea

Comment: So to understand correct: "My Example Table" is your source data?

Comment: The "Additional" is my source data. The "My Example Table" was my attempt at showing what my power pivot is doing